# JavaScript in JSP page with print button

Tags: javascript, jsp

Here is one JSP page.
It works and it belongs to the code I inherited and now I have to maintain it.

There is condition - already tested separately, works just OK, here is just substituted with: **if(true)**
and if condition is **true** then there should be PRINT button on that page.

Without JavaScript **if block** it works (there is print button), but with JavaScript **if block** it doesn't what I did wrong here?

UPDATE: Condition I am testing (and works and is satisfying for what I need) is:

if(!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)))

```
<%@ page import="com.xxxxx.xxxxx.constants.IParameter" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

      <input type="hidden" name="<%=IParameter.TAG_ACTION%>" value="">

      <div class="span12">
        <%@ include file="/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/instructions.jsp" %>
      </div>

      <div class="row-fluid" style="padding-top:20px">
        <hr>
        <a style="outline: medium none;" hidefocus="true" class="btn pull-left" a href="#" onclick="window.close()"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> <c:out value="${requestScope.STRING_MAP.CLOSE_WINDOW}"/></a>

        <script>
        if(true) 
           {
            <a style="outline: medium none;" hidefocus="true" class="btn pull-right" a href="#" onclick="window.print()"><i class="icon-print"></i> <c:out value="${requestScope.STRING_MAP.PRINT}"/></a>
           }
         </script>

      </div>
```

Comment: You can't put HTML in the middle of a `<script>` block like that. (Well, you can via JSX, but that just gives you a JavaScript string.) What is the actual condition you're trying to test? If it's something on the JSP side, then doing it with JavaScript is probably incorrect anyway.

Comment: @Pointy  see update in question. Should I try with: document.write('<a style="outline: medium none;" hidefocus="true" class="btn pull-right" a href="#" onclick="window.print()"><i class="icon-print"></i> <c:out value="${requestScope.STRING_MAP.PRINT}"/></a>');
           }

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below :

```
<%@ page import="com.xxxxx.xxxxx.constants.IParameter" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

      <input type="hidden" name="<%=IParameter.TAG_ACTION%>" value="">

      <div class="span12">
        <%@ include file="/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/instructions.jsp" %>
      </div>

      <div class="row-fluid" style="padding-top:20px">
        <hr>
        <a style="outline: medium none;" hidefocus="true" class="btn pull-left" a href="#" onclick="window.close()"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> <c:out value="${requestScope.STRING_MAP.CLOSE_WINDOW}"/></a>
 <a id="printButton" style="outline: medium none;" hidefocus="true" class="btn pull-right" a href="#" onclick="window.print()"><i class="icon-print"></i> <c:out value="${requestScope.STRING_MAP.PRINT}"/></a>
        <script>
        if(true) 
           {
           document.getElementById('printButton').style.display = "none";
           }
         </script>

      </div>
```